# How to update iPod touch from iOS3.1.3

Tags: ios

When I check for updates on my iPod touch (currently on iOS version 3.1.3) it tells me I am on the most recent software.

How can I update to a more recent iOS software?

Comment: Please mention the generation of your iPod Touch

Answer (score 1):

If it says you're on the most recent version with no updates available, it's either jailbroken and specifically modified, or there isn't an update available for your device.

If you have an iPod touch 1<sup>st</sup>-generation, iOS (or iPhone OS) 3.1.3 really is the latest version you can install on your device, and will show that there are no updates available.